# Find every DOM element covered by a certain element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, z-index

I have a certain DOM element on the page with a very high z-index and I need to find every element it overlaps (i.e, every element in the same-ish spot with a lower z-index)

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you could perform a loop of each element of DOM or each element that has a tag class saying it uses a z  index. Then you could check zindex like this if ( $('.yourClass').attr('z-index').val() < yourZindex ){do something}

Comment: right but in addition to having a lower z index it also must be positioned under the given element. your technique finds everything anywhere on the page w a lower z index whether or not it's under the element in question

Comment: You can use .next() in your test statement http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: it could be something like this: if ( $('.yourElement').next().attr('z-index') < yourZindex ){do something}

Comment: no because the covered element might be at the end of the document but position: fixed under the covering element

Comment: Well, if I got your question, the above code will  do nothing if "yourElement" is the last one, because next will return nothing. Same whay  we were traversing a list. If covered element is in the last position in the DOM it will be catch when pointer is over the previous element. And when loop pointer is over it, if conditions will return nothing

Answer (score 1):

To get all elements with a lower z-index you could use a filter and filter the elements based on z-index.

To get all elements that has a position that overlaps with a certain element is a little more tricky.
One needs to get the position of the corners of the overlaying element, and then compare that to the corners of each element to see if they overlaps somewhere.

All together, something like this

```
var reference = $('#overlay'),
    index     = reference.css('z-index'),
    square    = getDimensions(reference);

function getDimensions(elem) {
    var offset = elem.offset();
    return [offset.top, offset.top + elem.height(), offset.left, offset.left + elem.width()];
}

$('body *').not('script, style, :hidden').filter(function() {
    // only elements with lower z-index or without z-index
    var idx = $(this).css('z-index');
    return isNaN(idx) || (idx < index);
}).filter(function() {
    // only elements that intersect with the overlaying element
    var offset = getDimensions($(this));
    return ((offset[1] > square[0]) && (offset[0] < square[1])) &&
           ((offset[3] > square[2]) && (offset[2] < square[3]));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sah8mk3y/)